# Отправка несуществующих символов как обычных в Telegram

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Нужно сделать бота, который должен отправлять на запросы текст. Выглядит как самый обычный бот, однако текст может иметь в составе символы, которых вообще не существует в природе. То есть у меня изображение, рисунок "символа", и этот символ должен отображаться как обычный текст. Как это можно сделать?
P.S. я делаю бота на c#, однако, как я понимаю, прям большой разницы в подходах в реализации бота на различных яп нету

Comment: Насколько я знаю телеграм работает только с кодировкой Unicode и других символов отправлять не может

Comment: @ИванПавлов Я данном слчае то что надо отправить вообще не имеет кодировки. Это больше похоже на смайлик какой-нибудь. Возможно можно сделать это именно через изменение текстуры смайла. Но тогда если так то как это сделать?

Comment: чел смайлик - это тоже часть кодировки) Единственное, что недавно появился тг-премиум и там добавили анимированный стикеры которые можно в текст вставлять, посмотри как их самому делать, скорее всего нужен будет отдельный тг-бот для этого, ну или просто созвать набор обычных стикеров и перевести их в премиум (хз как)